# Wifi password lost every time I reboot my phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, password

VS985 - Verizon LG G3 - CM12 Nightly - 5.0.2

This has been going on for a few months now, and is just driving me bonkers. Every time I reboot my phone, and am home, my phone forgets the password for the wifi. All other devices in the house (iphone, ipad, laptops, kindles, chromecasts, etc.) do not have this issue.

This only happens for my home router – passwords for other networks are surviving reboots.

As I have my phone how I like it, I don't want to start from scratch. I tried wiping system, but it's like the password is a part of my personal data and that for some reason it is forgotten so often? Does anyone have ideas on how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: And you haven't asked this at the CM forum yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but a work-around:

The WiFi password is not stored on `/system` – it's in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. As you're using CyanogenMod, it should be safe to assume you're having root access. So you could use an automation tool (yes, I've got [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) in mind here) to copy that file to a "safe place" whenever shutting down the device, and have it restored from there on each boot.

Comment: This might work, however it does not explain why the password is getting lost each time. Other APs work without any issues. Is there a way to reset access points both on the device, and those synced with googled?

Comment: As written: not a solution (nor an explanation) – but at least better than nothing. You just introduced a new fact in your comment: this "Alzheimer" only happens to the password of this specific router – but not for others? If so, please include that fact with your question directly, might be an important pointer! (And gets myself even more confused on how that's possible – I've never heard about a feature like "session passwords" for WiFi)

Answer (score 0):

If its only happening for your router then I think it's because of your SSID name or password. Maybe they contain some uncommon characters. And maybe during boot CM is unable to resolve them correctly (characters not available in the encoding used for saving and reading the file), causing the loss.

Once I used the ¥(Yen) symbol in my password and my friends Lumia could not connect to it.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed permissions to 644 (from 660) on /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf. That helped (so it seems so far).

Comment: I think you wanted to comment on this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/102644/96277).

Comment: @Firelord You could count this as an alternative approach: Vedran removed the write permission for the group, so whatever it is obviously was unable to write to the file anymore. As the write-bit however is left for the owner, it *might* be the user still can store new connections. I have not tested that, so it's for ***Vedran*** to confirm my suspicion. // Vedran: Could you please add a few more details on what you did, and confirm it's still possible to add new connections after that?

Comment: @Izzy For clarification: I didn't down-vote this in case if you or anyone wonders! Or I could've posted a different comment.

Comment: @Firelord I didn't accuse you of anything here :) My addressing you also was just for clarification.